# Slope analysis in QGIS

Tags: qgis, slope

I have a 1/3 arc-second DEM downloaded from USGS that I am trying to use to create a slope analysis layer.

The DEM is in ESPG 4269 to start and I've re-projected it into NAD83 UTM Zone 11N (the DEM is for eastern Oregon) so the vertical and horizontal units are in meters.

The output looks correct except all of the lines through it (see screenshot).  Maybe I went wrong in how I projected it?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this post may help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191071/why-do-stripes-appear-on-raster/191077#191077 How did you reproject it? If you're using GDALWarp you could consider your resampling method, default is nearest which is fast but causes problems that look like this.

Comment: That was it!  I reprojected again, this time setting the resampling method to bilinear, and now I have an unlined output.  Thank you!

Comment: That's great news, I'll vote to close this thread as a duplicate so that users are directed toward the other post with more comments and an answer.