# Slope and hillshade layer not continuous in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, slope, hillshade

I have been trying to create slope and Hillshade rasters from a DEM raster, which is in UTM11N. I tried different ratios (vertical to horizontal) but everything is in meters so it should work fine. I get these stepping slopes going from 0˚ to 50˚ and back rather than a continuous slope. I was wondering if it was normal to have these lines rather than a continuous slope. If not what can I do to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: See this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351051/slope-analysis-in-qgis

Comment: Thank you. I tried reprojecting my DEM, but it was already in UTM11N. I tried reprojecting it using bilinear resampling, but it does not change any thing. I tried using the slope function on the reprojected DEM ans still get the same result.

Comment: That "herringbone" pattern that you see is a classic example of what happens to a DEM that - sometime in its history - has been subjected to a nearest neighbor resampling.  I'm confident enough to bet a pint on it!  I suggest that you find a copy of the *original, source* DEM and then process it as you need, being absolutely careful to assure that in every step forward (not just reprojecting; other raster processing tools involve resampling) that you always resample using something other than nearest neighbor.  I've always had good results with bilinear resampling.

Comment: Thank you I will try to download it from another source see if it solves the problem. Have a good day

Comment: Good luck, and please report back with your results!

Comment: For slope layers it's usual, under 'Layer Properties -> Symbology', to set 'Color gradient' to 'White to black'.

Comment: Hi all, so I tried it again with a new raser and it seem better, but I still get a weird grid in my data which I don't really know how to explain